# Java Selenium 2.0 - handle z-index (navi) when using builtin scroll before WebElement .click()

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

Selenium 2.0 .click() comes with automatic scrolling until the element is visible and allowed to be clicked to:

```
WebElement box = driver.findElement( By.id( boxID ) );
box.click();
```

This usually works fine, selenium will scroll until the box appears and then performs click().

Anyway it will fail with a *org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException* if an element with a higher z-index exists. It scrolls to the element, but its not visible because of the lower z-index. In my case a navigation-bar at the top of the page.

I thought of solving this with a javascript-scroll to the top of the page, so the element would appear at the bottom of the page but that might not be the best (or even a good) solution...

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
// scroll to top will make the box occur at the bottom of the page
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, -10000);");
```

Is there any elegant way to handle this through an entire test-suite without a hack like javascript scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String script = String.format(" $('.items-container').scrollTo($('li#%s'))",currentId);
```

Run your script with this line add the css or xpath that you need

Comment: This fix requires jquery, which is not part of the question. Besides that, it's close to the same of the scroll-action selenium itself will perform. Not usefull.